# Print md5 hash of an image opened with Python's PIL

Tags: python, md5, python-imaging-library

How can I open an image in PIL, then print the md5 hash of the image without saving it to a file and reading the file?

Comment: How are you opening the image to begin with?

Comment: If your intent is to generate the hash of the file, don't open the file with `PIL`, open it as a regular file. If your intent is to hash the image pixel values, see [`tostring`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.tostring).

Comment: @MarkRansom, when you say "image pixel values" do you mean the data in the image minus the EXIF tags? Yes this is exactly what I'm trying to do. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 22):

```
from PIL import Image
import hashlib

md5hash = hashlib.md5(Image.open('test.png').tobytes())
print(md5hash.hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 15):

You could save the image to a `io.BytesIO()`, and take the `md5` hash of its value:

```
import hashlib
import Image
import io

img = Image.open(FILENAME)
m = hashlib.md5()
with io.BytesIO() as memf:
    img.save(memf, 'PNG')
    data = memf.getvalue()
    m.update(data)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

This will compute the same md5 hash as if you saved the `Image` to a file, then read the file into a string and took the md5 hash of the string:

```
img.save(NEWFILE, 'PNG')
m = hashlib.md5()
data = open(NEWFILE, 'rb').read()
m.update(data)
print(m.hexdigest())
```

Note that if the `Image` was loaded from a lossy format such as `JPEG`, then the md5 hash you obtain might not be the same as the one you would obtain from the original file itself, not only because the above code saves the image in `PNG` format, but because, even if it were to re-save it as a `JPEG`, saving to a lossy format will produce different data.

Comment: `with io.BytesIO() as memf:` - If i'm not mistaken

Answer (score 6):

`PIL/Pillow` has an `Image` method [`tobytes`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.tobytes) (or [`tostring`](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.tostring) in older versions) that will store the image pixel values in a byte string. Simply run your hash algorithm on the returned byte string.

This will be more efficient than writing a specific format such as PNG, since it's the native representation used internally.

Comment: Note that tostring has been removed from PIL: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html?highlight=tostring

Comment: @kylegill thanks for the heads up, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Re: the comment: to ignore the exif, how about copying out the data into a new `Image` and md5 the string representation of that?

```
from PIL import Image
import md5

img = Image.open('test.png')
# assuming there is exif, if you should want it:
exif_data = img._getexif()
just_pixels = Image.new(img.mode, img.size)
just_pixels.putdata(img.getdata())

m = md5.new()
m.update(just_pixels.tostring())
```