# How do I make the image generation and hashing more efficient?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, hash

I am using code to create a random image and then I check the hash value of this image and compare it to a known hash value. Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
import hashlib
import numpy
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

def create_image(width = 1920, height = 1080, num_of_images = 100):
    width = int(width)
    height = int(height)
    num_of_images = int(num_of_images)

    current = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
    os.mkdir(current)
    i=0
    for n in range(num_of_images):
        filename = '{0}/{0}_{1:03d}.jpg'.format(current, n)
        rgb_array = numpy.random.rand(height,width,3) * 255
        image = Image.fromarray(rgb_array.astype('uint8')).convert('RGB')
        image.save(filename)
        imagee = open(filename, "rb").read()
        hashnum = hashlib.md5(imagee).hexdigest()

        if(hashnum=="B3D740C2F83F7EE120FD16EAED266B43"):
            image.save(filename)
            print(filename)
        else:
            os.remove(filename)
        i+=1
        print("Done with ", i, end='\r')

def main(args):
    create_image(width = args[0], height = args[1], num_of_images = args[2])
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys 
    status = main(sys.argv[1:])
    sys.exit(status)
```

So far this program is going through about 1k 17 width 14 height images per second and I was wondering if this could be more efficient. I thought about getting rid of the whole save image and then delete, but I am not really sure how to do that. Also sorry if this post has errors, English is not my first language.

Comment: If you have the hash of an existing image, you can never find the original image using this method. Firstly, it would require around 63,000 years if your image is 1080p resolution. Secondly, if you have the hash of the existing image, it must have been generated in the past, yet all images you generate will include a timestamp in the future in them, so they can never be identical. Speeding it up by avoiding disk I/O or adding multiprocessing isn't going to help. 

Answer (score 0):

[This answer shows you how to avoid having to save the Image to disk before hashing it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126596/print-md5-hash-of-an-image-opened-with-pythons-pil)

Removing disk write/read should make it significantly faster